# Как запаковать бинарную строку и записать её в файл?

Tags: c++

Всем привет!

Прошу помочь мне с вот такой штукой: у меня есть массив char из нулей ('0') и единиц ('1'), мне необходимо записать его в бинарный файл в запакованном виде, т.е. что бы каждый элемент занимал один бит.

Я очень много прочитал по этому поводу, но к сожалению, ничего не получается.

```
void OutputResult1(char **Result) {

  (*Result) = new char[1000];

  for (int i = 0; i < 1000 ;i++)
  {
    (*Result)[i] = 0;
  }

  int l = 0;

  for ( int i = 0; i<MyText.size(); i++)
  {
    while ( MyText[i] != W[l])
    {
      l++;
    }

    if ( MyText[i] == W[l])
    {
      strcat( (*Result) , bits[l]);
      l = 0;
    }
  }
}

char *BinaryCode;
OutputResult1(&BinaryCode);

ofstream fout("C:\\Okay.dat", ios::binary);
```

Что делать дальше?

Comment: А кто мешает использовать fwrite?

Comment: Я не знаю, как правильно вызвать эту функцию..

fwrite(buffer , 1 , sizeof(buffer) , ptrFile );

где ptrvoid
Указатель на массив элементов, которые необходимо записать в файл.
size
Размер в байтах каждого элемента массива.
count
Количество элементов, каждый из которых занимает size байт.
filestream
Указатель на объект типа FILE.

У меня каждый элемент массива не по 1 байту.. Мне необходимо до жути, что бы каждый элемент массива  ( у меня там только 0 и 1) весил при записи в бин.файл - бит.. Только тогда у меня получится сжать файл..

Comment: Если вам что-то надо до жути и вы спрашиваете - попробуйте внятно сформулировать что и во что должно быть преобразовано. В самом вопросе, желательно с примерами.

Comment: У меня есть строка из 0 и 1. Этой строкой у меня закодировано сообщение. Данную строку мне нужно записать в бинарный файл.

Comment: В таком случае, Вы неверно формулируете вопрос. Вам надо не перенести массив в файл, а сначала нужно сжать последовательность из нулей и единиц так, чтобы каждый ноль или единица занимала 1 бит. Затем уже всё это пойдёт в файл.

Comment: Прошу Вас, скажите, хоть что-нибудь скажите по этому поводу.. Как? Как это сделать?

Comment: воспользуйтесь `strtol` или чем то вроде `char str[8]; unsigned char byte=0; for(int i=0;i<8;i++) byte=(byte<<1) | (str[i]&1);`

Comment: Спасибо.. Скорее всего мне попросту придется переписывать алгоритм сжатия.. И кодировать не строкой из 0 и 1 каждый символ, а как-то иначе. Жаль..

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Смотрю у вас в теге C++. Значит будем с ним работать не на жуткой смеси из Си и C++.

Перво наперво, помимо данных, записанных в массив, вам нужно знать и их размер, что бы потом сказать `fout.write(...)`
сколько данных вы хотите записать. Тут вам как нельзя лучше подойдёт `std::vector` собственно ваша функция принимает вид (я сохраню передачу массива для заполнения в качестве параметра, возможно в этом кроется какой-то глубинный смысл):

```
#include <vector>

void OutputResult1(std::vector<char> &Result) {

  Result.clear(); // вообще цикл с занулением можно было заменить одним memset.
  Result.reserve(1000); // только резервируем память, Result.size() вернёт ноль.

  size_t l = 0;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < MyText.size(); ++i)
  {
    // Оставлю на вашей совести проверку выхода за пределы границ в W и bits
    while (MyText[i] != W[l])
    {
      l++;
    }

    if ( MyText[i] == W[l])
    {
      Result.push_back(bits[l]);
      l = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Ну а вызов и запись делаются просто:

```
// Обратите внимание, указателей тут не используем, используем передачу по ссылке
std::vector<char> BinaryCode;
OutputResult1(BinaryCode);

ofstream fout("C:\\Okay.dat", ios::binary);

// для верности проверим
if (fout) {
    // и запишем
    fout.write(BinaryCode.data(), BinaryCode.size());
}
```

Вариант выше просто запишет последовательно из 0 и 1 в файл и прочитать его можно как есть. Но согласно вашим комментариям, вы хотите запаковать их до 1 бита. Что ж... Тут варианта ровно два:

1. Оставить вызывающий код как есть и малость переделать `OutputResult1` что бы она сразу, по ходу пьессы "кодировала" данные
2. Оставить функцию `OutputResult1` как есть и изменить запись в файл.

Рассмотрим оба варианта.

**Вариант 1: изменяем `OutputResult1`**

```
#include <vector>
#include <bitset> // std::bitset

void OutputResult1(std::vector<char> &Result) {

  Result.clear(); // вообще цикл с занулением можно было заменить одним memset.
  Result.reserve(1000); // только резервируем память, Result.size() вернёт ноль.

  // пакуем в один байт
  std::bitset<8> outbits;
  size_t         curbit = 0;

  size_t l = 0;
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < MyText.size(); ++i)
  {
    // Оставлю на вашей совести проверку выхода за пределы границ в W и bits
    while (MyText[i] != W[l])
    {
      l++;
    }

    if ( MyText[i] == W[l])
    {
      // я не знаю, что хранится в bits, предполагаю '1' и '0'
      outbits.set(curbit++, bits[l] == '1');

      // Как только текущий бит дойдёт до 8 - запишем в Result
      if (curbit == outbits.size()) {
        Result.push_back(static_cast<char>(outbits.to_ulong()));
        curbit = 0;
        outbits.reset();
      }
      l = 0;
    }
  }
  // тут нужно проверить, что curbit 0, иначе скинуть "недописанный" байт в Result
  if (curbit) {
    Result.push_back(static_cast<char>(outbits.to_ulong()));
  }
}
```

**Вариант 2: изменяем вызывающий код**

Собственно он делается аналогично.

```
// Обратите внимание, указателей тут не используем, используем передачу по ссылке
std::vector<char> BinaryCode;
OutputResult1(BinaryCode);

ofstream fout("C:\\Okay.dat", ios::binary);

// для верности проверим
if (fout) {
    // и запишем... но не сразу.

    std::vector<char> bitvec;
    bitvec.reserve(BinaryCode.size() / 8 + 1); // +1 на всякий случай, если у нас некратное 8 число "бит"

    std::bitset<8> outbits;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < BinaryCode.size(); ++i) {
        size_t bit = i % 8; // остаток от деления на 8 всегда будет от 0 до 7
        outbits.set(bit, BinaryCode[i] == '1');
        if (bit == outbits.size() - 1) {
            bitvec.push_back(static_cast<char>(outbits.to_ulong()));
            outbits.reset();
        }
    }

    // размер некратен 8, значит есть недозаполненый байт, сохраним его
    if (BinaryCode.size() % 8) {
        bitvec.push_back(static_cast<char>(outbits.to_ulong()));
        outbits.reset();
    }

    fout.write(bitvec.data(), bitvec.size());
}
```

**Заключение**

Код выше писался как демонстрация идеи, по памяти и не првоерялся на компилябельность и работоспособность - данные процедуры возлагаю на плечи топик-стартера.

Comment: Кстати, есть ещё вариант с `std::vector<bool>`, можете сами изучить его и его подводные камни.

Comment: Спасибо большое... Жаль я сейчас только случайно снова открыл закладку со своим вопросом.. Мб пригодиться кому-нибудь и мое решение этой проблемы:

Comment: OutputResult1(&BinaryCode);

     for(int i = 0; i<strlen(BinaryCode); i++)
     {
      if(BinaryCode[i] == 48)
      {
       x.push_back(0);
      }

      else
      {
       x.push_back(1);
      }
     }

     ofstream g ("C:\\Okay.bin");

     int amount = 0;
     char buf = 0;

      for(int j = 0; j<x.size(); j++)
   {
    buf = buf | x[j] << (7 - amount);
    amount++;
    if(amount == 8)
    {
     amount = 0;
     g<<buf;
     buf = 0;
    }
     }

      g.close();